# I try to create stored procedure that received 3 parameters, if any param its value equal "-1" it'll not be included in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

It can be like this form?
I try select case but error always occur.
if there is any help i'll be thankful.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE searchStatement
    (
    @word1 varchar(50),
    @word2 varchar(50),
    @word3 varchar(50)
    )

as
select * from words where 1=1 
if @word1 <> '-1'
and word1 =@word1 
if @word2 <> '-1'
and word2 =@word2 
if @word3 <> '-1'
and word3 =@word3
```

Comment: Can you expand that code a littlebit?  It is looking you are going to need different select statements based on what paramaters are passed.  What is Select words where 1=1 going to return?  Thanks.

Comment: No i don't want different select statements , i just want to append conditions to the same select statement based on parameters values

Comment: I've given a solution which closure to your problem. Please take a look at this that will sort it out your case

Comment: Gail Shaw's [solution](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the condition via `if` statement and form a `string query` as like below then you can execute the string `query` through `exec` command.

```
declare @resultSet nvarchar(max)
set @resultSet = 'select *from searchStatement where 1= 1  '

if @word1 <> '-1' 
begin
set @resultSet = @resultSet +  ' and word1 = '+@word1
end

if @word2 <> '-1' 
begin
set @resultSet = @resultSet +  ' and word2 = '+@word2
end

if @word3 <> '-1' 
begin
set @resultSet = @resultSet +  ' and word3 = '+@word3
end

 exec(@resultSet)
```

Comment: +1 . . . This has the advantage that it will use indexes readily on the fields in the `where` clause (if available).

Answer (score 2):

you could use this:

```
select *.
from word
where
    (@word1 = '-1' or word = @word1) and
    (@word2 = '-1' or word = @word2) and
    (@word3 = '-1' or word = @word3)
```

BTW, if you want to give an empty parameter into procedures, it's better to use null instead of -1

Comment: You say you could use case and then give an example without case?

Comment: :) sorry. I've just realized that I don't get a problem. If OP want to get all data matched with not -1 words, then my query is incorrect.

Comment: As far as I can tell your answer produces the result the OP wants.

Comment: +1 . . . This has the advantage of being a common approach to this problem that does not require dynamic SQL (and hence recompiling the query).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. The one that is closest to your 'if idea' is something like this:

```
select *
from word
where
  1 = 1 
  and
  case
    when @word1 <> '-1'
    then word1 = @word1
    else 1 = 1
  end 
  and
  case
    when @word2 <> '-1'
    then word2 = @word2
    else 1 = 1
  end 
  and
  case
    when @word3 <> '-1'
    then word3 = @word3
    else 1 = 1
  end
```

There are shorter easier to understand solutions though (like the ones in the other answers).

Comment: Yes , thanks that what i want but the syntax not correct it appear this message (Incorrect syntax near '='.) ? sorry am not strong in SP and i need it :)

Comment: @AhmedSalameh it won't work because we can't write condtion expression after then statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "if" like that. Use a "where" like this:

```
select * from words
where @word1 in ( '-1', word1)
and word2 in ( '-1', word2)
and word3 in ( '-1', word3);
```

IMHO using `IN()` results in a more elegant query than using `OR`.